# How do browsers handle cookies?

Tags: java, web-applications, cookies, browser

How does a browser manage cookies? I mean, does it have to create cookie the object?

Motivation: I want to log in to a cookie site. Nowadays cookies are not only name and value - they also contain domain, expiry date, etc.

I need the answer in Java prospective.

Comment: No, the server creates cookie the object, and the browser sticks it into its cookie jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a browser receives a response containing a specific cookie header, it creates a cookie.

With the java servlet API you can create cookies by:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie();
cookie.setName(); // setValue, setMaxAge, setPath, etc.
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

On subsequent requests the browser sends the cookies to the server. Again, with the servlet API, you can obtain the current cookies by calling `request.getCookies()`

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to build a mini-browser with cookie state using java.net built-in API, you can check out this tutorial: http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html. It shows how can Java connect to a URL, go through response headers to fetch cookies, and how to set cookies in a request.

Some example code:

```
    System.out.println("GET: " + url);

    // create and open url connection for reading
    URL urlObj = new URL(url);
    URLConnection conn = urlObj.openConnection();

    // set existing cookies
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myGetSavedCookies(url));

    // connect
    conn.connect();

    // loop through response headers to set new cookies
    myAddSavedCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

    // read page
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
    while (sc.hasNextLine())
        out.write(sc.nextLine());
    sc.close();
```

Comment: I tried according to the tutorial but it is not working .But I have a confusion abut the first parameter of the requestproperty is simply "Cookie" .What are they trying to say by this string . Is it only a string or it is cookie name or what????

Comment: It is a constant key, indicating what the second argument is. You can specify more than one cookie by separating key=value pairs with ';'. For reference on this method, see [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working on the server and working in a Servlet environment (Tomcat, Jetty), then you want to look at [getCookies](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29) and the similar set cookies in the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to automate browsing a web site from the client perspective, instead of doing it by hand, I would use a framework like [JWebUnit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin/index.html), which is based on [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) but is even higher-level and easier to use. You don't have to worry about cookies, but you have access to them if you need to examine them.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question of how the browser handles cookies, but I hope it helps!